# Params hash element sent from form is nil in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table called Part with the columns "mp3_link", "caption", "translation", "position",  and "lesson_id".

"position" refers to order of a part instance in a list of part instances.

I created a edit view for the Part model, where the above attributes can be changed.  This includes the "position" attribute:

```
<div class="control-group">
<%= f.label :position, class: 'control-label' %>
<div class="controls">
<%= f.text_field :position %>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is in the update controller, the code part_params[:position] gives me nil.

I used "debug params" to see the content of the hash.  The "position" element has a value (in this case '4'):

```
mp3_link: https://w.soundcloud.com
caption: 不借認這多把樣去利是
translation: non eaque natus aliquid at rerum sequi quibusdam necessitatibus doloribus
position: '4'
commit: Save
action: update
controller: parts
id: '5'
```

So the "position" value is being sent from the form, but for some reason, in the update controller, part_params[:position] gives me nothing.  I can see this by printing it out in the update view.

In the controller:

```
@out = part_params[:position]
```

In the view:

```
<%= @out %>
```

Nothing prints out.  But when I try another element of the hash, for example

```
@out = part_params[:mp3_link]
```

Then it works fine.
What could be going on here?

Comment: post your controller and your edit form. and which version of rails you are using?

Comment: What is `part_params`? Try to use `params[:part][:position]`

Comment: debug/ write to console and see what params.keys contains, may be one of the values is :posistion, or some such

Comment: params[:part][:position] indeed works.  I guess part_params is some kind of syntactic sugar that doesn't work quite the way I expected it to.

Comment: Include position in your strong parameters, guessing this is set up in`part_params` method?